# Convert string to a name identifer

Tags: c, string, stringify

Is the "destringification" possible in C89 just like [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) is possible?

Comment: Are you asking in general (in which case the answer is probably no) or are you trying to achieve a particular task by destringifying?

Comment: I am trying to access the variable, named in a string. A variable name can be compared with a string and its value can be accessed through a pointer in this case. The question is how to connect these things.

Comment: Something like declaring `void* **list` and a macro `#define declare(type, name, init) type name = init; {//3dallocation, *list[num] = #name &list[num] = name;} ...`

Comment: So it's really more like a symbol lookup. Why do you want this to be done via a string? Is the string provided by the user?

Comment: Yes. As a user input. The user input the name of the variable in the console and the console output its value. How isn't that useful.. especially for development libraries.

Comment: It looks like your use case is for debugging? If so, gdb already handles this since you can print variable values at run time under gdb.

Answer (score 2):

Variables names are translated into symbol names at compile time. These symbols are supposed not to be accessible from inside the program and their names often get mangled, but anyway, C does not provide a way to access his own runtime from the inside. This kind of feature in a programming language is called "reflection", and if you rely on its existence for your project you should look up a language featuring it, or, as I would suggest, use some sort of 2D map or dictionary, which are data structures in which each object is associated with a unique key, often a string, making it easy to look it up in the way you seem to be needing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a macro DESTRINGIFY("hello") to be expanded to hello. In that case, NO, it is NOT possible in C89 as well as in later standards.

Comment: Well name identifiers must be stored as a string somewhere in the memory. I think DESTRINGIFY is possible on way way or another..

Comment: @AlanSalios: No, they usually are not stored in memory, only identifiers with external linkage are.

Comment: Ahh yes.. I forgot about that.